# The property ... could not be mapped, because it is of type 'string[]' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

This code is auto-generated class using paste special for XML.

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class PersonName
{
    private string firstNameField;

    private string surnameField;

    private string[] originalScriptNameField;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.firstNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.firstNameField = value;
        }
    }

    public string Surname
    {
        get
        {
            return this.surnameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.surnameField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("OriginalScriptName")]
    public string[] OriginalScriptName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.originalScriptNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.originalScriptNameField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and I am using Entity Framework (Code-First) and in my context class

```
public DbSet<PersonName> PersonNames { get; set; }
```

But during run time, I get this error

> The property ... could not be mapped, because it is of type 'string[]'
> which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either
> explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]'
> attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
> 'OnModelCreating'.'

Comment: Don't you have answer " Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.'" already in the question? Not really sure what you are asking here...

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, there are no field types in most common databases called array.

Fix 1

Don't do that. Usually you would put these things in another table (related entity).

Fix 2 (`ValueConverter` hackery)

[Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions)

> Value converters allow property values to be converted when reading
> from or writing to the database.
>
> **Warning**
>
> Use of value conversions may impact the ability of EF Core to
> translate expressions to SQL

**Example**

```
var converter = new ValueConverter<string[], string>(
    x => string.Join(";",x),
    x => x.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));


modelBuilder.Entity<PersonName>()
                .Property(e => e.OriginalScriptName)
                .HasConversion(converter);
```

<sub>***Note** : Obviously the above can fail in a multitude of ways, it's your mission to make it work for your situation.*</sub>

Comment: The problem is the auto-generated class from `paste XML as classes` generated tonnes of array field type.

Comment: @Steve yeah you will have problems with that, generate XML classes will not work well with entity framework, However you can create your own model, and map your serialized xml to them, or massage them together which is likely not optimal for complex types